# Eclipse: Taking ALL of my preferences with me between copies of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, export, preferences

I'm using the Spring Tool Suite, which I think is based on Eclipse 3.7.2

I set a number of syntax color coding preferences in Java and XML in mycopy of Eclipse at work. I then exported my preferences to a

eclipsePrefs.epf

I just tried importing my preferences into my copy of Eclipse at home from

eclipsePrefs.epf

There were only checkboxes for the Java preferences, not the XML syntax coloring or other preferences. I tried "import all". No dice.

How can I move all of my color coding....and other, preferences between copies of Eclipse?

Have a good weekend

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All settings are stored in a folder called `.metadata` (hidden) in the current workspace. There is a `plugin` folder within with settings and preferences for each plugin, including the core of Eclipse.

Please see this guide: http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w

Comment: So, if I changed syntax colors in WorkSpace_A, those changes wouldn't be there for me, with the same copy of Eclipse, in WorkSpace_B?

Comment: Seems like it. I've added a link to a nice guide.